# Cannot install packet mysql-workbench-gpl on debian squeeze

Tags: mysql, debian

if I try to install mysql-workbench-gpl  on debian squeeze I get to following error message (it's complaining about unresolved dependencies):

```
Probieren Sie »apt-get -f install«, um dies zu korrigieren:
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 mysql-workbench-gpl : Hängt ab von: libatkmm-1.6-1 (>= 2.22.1) ist aber nicht installierbar
                       Hängt ab von: libcairomm-1.0-1 (>= 1.6.4) soll aber nicht installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: libctemplate0 soll aber nicht installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) ist aber nicht installierbar
                       Hängt ab von: libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.28.0) soll aber nicht installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: libgnome-keyring0 (>= 2.22.2) soll aber nicht installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) aber 2.20.1-2 soll installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0) soll aber nicht installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: liblua5.1-0 soll aber nicht installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: libpangomm-1.4-1 (>= 2.27.1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: libpcre3 (>= 8.10) aber 8.02-1.1 soll installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: libpython2.7 (>= 2.7) ist aber nicht installierbar
                       Hängt ab von: libstdc++6 (>= 4.5) aber 4.4.5-8 soll installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: libzip1 (>= 0.8) soll aber nicht installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: python-paramiko soll aber nicht installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: python-pexpect soll aber nicht installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: python-pysqlite2 soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt-get -f install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).
```

How can I force to install the packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you downloaded is a deb package for ubuntu systems only. In your case with debian you will need to build the source version mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.40-src.tar.gz and build it manually. The way to do this should be inside the tar.gz file.